# Como hacer que docker run sea permanente

Tags: docker

Tengo la siguiente linea:

```
docker run -p 3001:3001 --network="host" --env-file "/home/ubuntu/server/tiledesk/.env" tiledesk/tiledesk-server
```

Y que se ejecute al principio del sistema, y que este de modo persistente alguien sabe? gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma mas sencilla es usar el sistema de auto-restart de docker:

1.- Primero dejar ejecutando el contenedor con los parametros deseados

```
docker run --name=MYDOCKERSERVICE -p 3001:3001 --network="host" --env-file "/home/ubuntu/server/tiledesk/.env" tiledesk/tiledesk-server
```

2.- Obtener el *Container ID* de la imagen en ejecucion (puedes usar `docker ps`)

2.- Ajustar el modo de recuperacion para que se ejecute al iniciar o al cerrarse inesperadamente (sirve para ambos casos)

```
docker update --restart=always CONTAINER_ID
```

Donde CONTAINERID es el contenedor ejecutado anteriormente.

Comment: Gracias me salvaste el dia!